# Why does my bench power supply current readout not match the set point?

Tags: power-supply

I have a Korad KD3005D bench power supply in constant current mode with a 10 ohm, 10 watt resistor as a load. The readout current never matches the set point. Why?

Using a BM235 multimeter as the load, the measured current on the meter is slightly higher than the set point.

Here's some data:

```
Set point: 1.000
Readback: 0.996

Set point: 1.006
Readback: 1.000

Set point: 0.800
Readback: 0.796

Set point: 0.804
Readback: 0.800

Set point: 0.600
Readback: 0.597

Set point: 0.603
Readback: 0.600
```

Some theories are:

- The display and the voltage control feedback are reading different values (separate resistors, separate ADCs.)
- The voltage control loop is analog but the readback is digital.
- The low current is 'close enough' that the controller doesn't increase the voltage.

Edit:

I understand this is normal for bench supplies and am still curious as to why the difference exists. Maybe better phrasing of the question: Since the supply was given a digital setpoint and produces a digital readout, why is the controller not making them equal?

Comment: The differences are within 1%. Why do you care? I suspect that this is well within the specified accuracy limits for both the setpoint and the reading.

Comment: Sounds normal to me.

Comment: I understand this is normal for bench supplies and am still curious as to why the difference exists.

Comment: @CraigYounkins That EDIT of yours completely changes the question -- sufficiently so that the existing answers are no longer even close to the ballpark of your real question. Just FYI.

Comment: theory #2 explains it completely. While they could "peek" at the display voltage with the MCU and bump up the output drive ref to compensate, that means that you would be controlling current via software, which sucks because it's always slower than an analog loop. So it actually performs much better being slightly off than it would if they "cheated" to make those match and left you with an output that jumped around on a few stairs, always slightly behind the load demands.

Answer (score 4):

A quick check shows that PSU available for €58. I don't think you're paying for a precision instrument.

A quick look at the [datasheet](https://static.eleshop.nl/mage/media/downloads/Korad_KD3000_Series_Datasheet-Web.pdf) shows the following:

[image]

Setup accuracy is ≤ 150 ppm + 10 mA. At 1 A that's 10 mA and you're worrying about a 6 mA error. There are a few others which will add to the errors but that's the main one.

I think you're doing OK!

Comment: Thanks! I do understand that this is not the world's most precise instrument. Maybe my question better phrased: since the supply was given a digital setpoint and produces a digital readback, why is the controller not making them equal?

Comment: @CraigYounkins Because, within the closed loop that is attempting to make them equal there is an *unknown and uncorrected offset*. The system can only be approximate. If you were trying to stick a tack into a cork-board at some exact location, using your hands, arms, body, eyes, brain, etc., in some giant feedback loop, you would still have some residual "offset" in how well you could poke that needle into the right spot. You might complain that your vision isn't precise enough -- but that's the point. It's not precise enough. So there would be some residual offset that someone could measure.

Comment: I agree the offset is uncorrected, but it is known by the machine's own readings. It stores the setpoint and displays the readback. I could do my own control loop by changing it to CV mode and turning the voltage dial with my hand to get the desired current reading.

Comment: @CraigYounkins Yes, you can correct the offset manually. That's called "reseting." But you are using a device you consider as "true" for your observation. If you were to insert your meter into the device and let it use your measuring device for control, it likely would do better. Especially if you used the same device to measure the error. Of course, if you bought a 2nd one for that purpose, you might still observe an offset. Just a different one.

Comment: Your measurements give an rms error without knowing which is most accurate.

Answer (score 1):

The Error applies to the shunt used for the ADC in PSU. This causes a gain error of <= 0.5% plus offset of 0.02.  The ADC does not correct the DAC digitally. They are independent analog error amplifiers.  Although in my bench PSU, they are digitally corrected so no error in the digital domain with 4 digits of resolution. Accuracy unknown but pretty good.

Davie Jones has promoted the DMM as the best bang for the buck in a small package.

Yet the specs for current in the 6A range are 0.7% + 3d.

All errors are less than spec. so you need to calibrate your internal shunt R in both devices  to some NIST traceable standard, if you wish to get better results.(!)

Suggestion: Learn how to do tolerance stackups.

Comment: Thanks! Please see the edit made to the post. The measurements with the DMM were just as a 3rd data point, not as a reference. The question is more about why the voltage control loop basically says, "Eh, close enough".

Comment: Any questions how to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

### Note about changing questions mid-stream

You've edited your question into something new. I understand that you think it is related to the earlier question. But answers showing you that the specifications allow the error you measured (we don't know how NIST/DIN traceable your measuring instrument is, but let's hold that question off for a bit) are now no longer addressing your question. In effect, the question has totally changed.

So I have the benefit of being able to direct my answer to your new question. An unfair advantage regarding your new question:

> Since the supply was given a digital setpoint and produces a digital
> readback, why is the controller not making them equal?

### An attempt

Suppose you have two measuring devices, \$M_1\$ and \$M_2\$. When you grab them off the shelf, measuring device \$M_1\$ has an instrument uncertainty of \$20\:\text{mA}\$ and measuring device \$M_2\$ has an instrument uncertainty of \$500\:\mu\text{A}\$.

By uncertainty I don't mean to suggest that it is entirely random each time a measurement takes place. What I mean, instead, is that the measurements against **True** are unknown by that much. This unknown value is due to initial accuracy errors, long term drift over temperature and time, measurement noise, etc.

You can choose to calibrate them just before using them. Just give yourself a vast research lab staffed with physicists who are in regular and continual communication with one of the few world-class standards labs such as NIST or DIN, toss the instrument over the wall and tell them to "calibrate this for me" and they will provide you with a complete table of adjustments to make after you take a reading in order to provide you with more accurate values. This could serve, within noise bounds anyway and so long as the instrument temperature and other vagaries are in tight control between the time they generated that table for you and your use of the instrument.

But let's say you don't have those resources handy.

So, your power supply uses the cheaper \$M_1\$ to make its measurements of current. It takes a current reading, calculates the difference between that reading and the set-point value, and just adjusts its control value to set the output current. If the the power supply's knowledge of that controller is perfect, it always knows exactly how to adjust the control value to yield the right current, so the output current will suddenly become equal to the set-point value.

Even so, given the range of error in \$M_1\$, while the power supply with its perfect current controller knowledge still almost certainly has an error in the current when measured by \$M_2\$, because \$M_2\$ is a better instrument with smaller residual error against **True**.

Why doesn't the power supply correct the error seen by \$M_2\$? Because it can't. It's using \$M_1\$ for its observations. And even having perfect knowledge of its own current controller won't make things any better.

Of course, the fact is that the current controller also has initial accuracy errors, temperature drift, time drift, etc. All the usual culprits. So the control output has to have at least *some* part of it that is "out of the control loop" had therefore also has some unknown gain that is different from "1" and an offset that also isn't observed. These cannot be adjusted for by the loop itself. They can only be "calibrated out," as well.

Now, you could choose to design an instrument so that you are allowed to plug in an "offset" or even a whole table of offsets. And if the instrument is really nice about this, it would measure its own temperature in all the right places within it, so that you could expand this table along different dimensions of known variation so that it corrects for all manner of varying situations. You could even enter "meter lead" corrections, as well! It could even take into account thermocouple effects with the right a priori knowledge! And so long as you had that expansive physicist lab handy to create the table for you and keep it updated, your instrument measurements could be pretty accurate.

Of course, the point is that none of this exists for most of us.

We have to get by with affordable solutions which make compromises. They use parts with lower initial accuracy, parts that drift over temperature and time, and are noisy. To help consumers interpret the results better, manufacturers attempt to include an honest evaluation of the net result of all these compromises into a few simple numbers that summarize them. So that you have an idea about what to expect when you use that instrument.

Finally? Even \$M_2\$ has its limitations. Even if you were to plug that into your power supply so that it could make more accurate measurements (and assuming it had a current controller of equal quality added into it so that it has a reasonable chance at controlling the current as well as its new measurement device can observe it), it would still have an uncontrolled offset -- ***if*** observed by a still more accurate measuring device, say \$M_3\$.

And if you had two \$M_2\$ devices, say \$M_{2a}\$ and \$M_{2b}\$, they might read differently, within their error bands (known and unknown.) So while the control loop might use \$M_{2a}\$, you might find that \$M_{2b}\$ disagrees. You might observe that as an "offset" in your mind, if you assumed that \$M_{2b}\$ was *truer* than \$M_{2a}\$. But there would be no way to know that, unless you'd recently calibrated one or the other against NIST-traceable standards and had that table handy to make appropriate corrections.

In the example I gave in comments, about trying to stick a thumb-tack into a cork-board, you have your eyes as your source of accuracy in terms of whether or not "you got it placed accurately." You have limitations in your muscle control, heart beat jitter, stability, and a host of other factors in being able to control the position of the thumb-tack just before sticking it into the cork-board. All of these things contribute to an ***offset*** between where you actually place it and where it actually should have been placed. And there's nothing much you can do about it without changing "the loop."

You could get magnifying glasses or a microscope. This would likely allow you to make better error measurements about the thumb-tack placement. But then you'd still have all the problems associated with brain-to-thumb-tack control of nerves, muscles, heart jitter and so on to deal with. You could improve that part by adding placement machinery using screw threads in 2-axes for creating a higher precision in placing the thumb-tack that copes with your body vagaries better.

But then you've just made the entire system more expensive.

And even then, there is still measurement bias error (lens and optical distortion vs thumb-tack tip position and its distance from the cork board) that means it's like "looking at a straw that's partially in water and out of it" and keeps you from ever really seeing the position error entirely accurately and there will be backlash errors in your positioning equipment, vibration from the local environment, etc.

The problem isn't anywhere else but in your mind. You need to repair that.